# AWS RDS: why is there "write IOPS" in my replica instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

The following is a PostgreSQL replica instance. I have no idea why there is `write IOPS` in my dashboard.

From my understanding, only `read` happens in replica instance.

[image]

Comment: Replica needs to keep up with master, therefore there are write ops in order to keep it consistent

Comment: Primary and replica sync changes through WAL. I suppose all replica needs to do is apply WAL to itself and there is no need to `execute` the SQL statement.

https://severalnines.com/database-blog/postgresql-streaming-replication-deep-dive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have writes from the master node as data is replicated.

Additionally any interactions that use temp tables would perform a local write to disk.

Comment: you are saying `write IOPS`  in replica is actually a copy of the primary database?

Comment: Writes IOPS in replica: writes IOPS in primary

Comment: Read IOPS in replica: read of primary + read of replica.

Comment: So write IOPs in replica are both the replicated data being written to disk from the master, and the temp DB. Read IOPs in replica are just the reading from the disk/DB for that node only. Replicas do not pull in changes, they are pushed asynchronously from the master db

Answer (score 0):

A Postgres database replica contains all of the data storage (tablespaces and other internally-managed files) that are present on the primary instance. The difference is that these data files are updated based on information in the write-ahead log (WAL) rather than user-submitted inserts/updates/deletes.

In addition, as a commenter noted, Postgres also uses temporary tables that may be flushed to disk, even for read-only queries.

In practice, you will need *at least* as many total IOPS for your replicas as you need for the primary, because the replica will typically be performing IO-intensive queries *in addition to* the updates received from the primary.